# Is it possible to have a filter per operation on canvas?

Tags: canvas

On canvas, is it possible to apply a filter to one drawing operation, but not another?

```
ctx.font = '48px serif';

ctx.filter = 'blur(4px)';
ctx.fillText('This is blurry', 30, 60);    

ctx.filter = undefined;
ctx.fillText('This should not be blurry', 60, 100);
```

I'd like the first text to be drawn fuzzy, but the second to be sharp. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` does not accept `undefined`. The value you're looking for is `'none'`:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.font = '48px serif';

ctx.filter = 'blur(4px)';
ctx.fillText('This is blurry', 30, 60);  

ctx.filter = 'none';
ctx.fillText('This should not be blurry', 60, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```